# Write an object manager to load / manage custom modules

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, oop

**Hey Guys,**

I have some questions about programming an object manager :

I want to write an application that uses an object manager to load custom modules. The code for the OM currently looks like this :

```
class OM :
    
    Registered_Modules = { }
    
    def __init__( Self , Debug_Mode = False ) :
       
        Self.Debug_Mode = Debug_Mode
        Self.Registered_Modules = OM.Registered_Modules
        
        print( f"Debug Mode : {Debug_Mode}" )

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    def Load_Module( Self , Module = '' ) :
       
        if( Module ) :
    
            Module_Properties = OM.Register_Module( Self , Module )
            return( Module_Properties )
            
        else :           
            print( f"[  ERROR  ] No Module Specified !" )
    
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def Register_Module( Self , Module , *Args , **KWT_Args ) :
        
        if( Module not in Self.Registered_Modules ) :
        else :
            return Registered_Modules[ Module ]           
        
        Module_Descriptor = Module.split( "::" , -1 )[ -1 ]   
      
        Module_FH = Module
        Module_FH = Module_FH.replace( '::' , '/' ) + '.py'
       
        if( os.path.exists( os.getcwd( ) + "/" + Module_FH ) == False ) :        
            return
         
        Module_Instance = importlib.import_module( Module.replace( '::' , "." ) )
       
        Module_Methods = [ method_name for method_name in dir( Module_Instance )
        if callable(getattr( Module_Instance , method_name ) ) ]
        
        Module_Attributes = getattr( Module_Instance , 'Loader' )( ) 
      
        Self.Registered_Modules.update( { Module_Descriptor : Module_Attributes } )
       
      # return( Self.Registered_Modules[ Module ] )
        return( Module_Instance )
        
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The following code uses the OM to load modules :

```
from OM import *

class VTE:

    def __init__( Self ):  
        
        print( "Testumgebung" )
        
        Self.OM_Core = OM( )
        
        Self.OM_Core.Load_Module( 'Testumgebung' )
        CFG  = Self.OM_Core.Load_Module( 'Testumgebung::Test::Neu' )
      
        Test2 = CFG.Config_Loader( Self )      
        print( Test2.Test )

VTE = VTE( )
```

So I want to use the instance 'Module_Instance' to load individual parts of the application. The variables are in the array 'Module_Attributes', e.g. with a config all config variables.

Questions :

1. In order to make the 'OM.Registered_Modules' variable available in all modules of the application, I have to make the variable available globally, right ?
2. Do you see any serious errors, or maybe you have suggestions for improvement. I would be very happy for advice.

Thanks a lot.

Best regards

NumeroUnoDE

Comment: Can someone please help me with this issue ? It's quite important to promote my code / application :)